# How to customize a CodedUI test search property - specifically window title

Tags: c#, customization, coded-ui-tests

Suppose I am trying to automate notepad, and depending on what is open, the tile of the window is either "Notepad", "Notepad - letter_to_boyfriend.txt", "Notepad - Readme.txt", etc.

When I recorded the coded ui test, it assumed the title "Notepad". Now I want to customize the test somehow, so that any title that looks like "Notepad*" would be good enough.

How can I do so? Sorry, I do not have recorded code to share at the moment, but I might later. Hopefully it is not that hard to reproduce.

It has got to be the search property.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Doubleclick on the [mapname].uitest, in the UI Control Map select your window, press F4 to see properties, and finally in Search Properties change the Operator from EqualsTo to Contains and the Value to "Notepad".

Comment: I want the property to be flexible to accept any string which matches a regular expression "Notepad*" or code the equivalent behavior by hand. How can I do that?

Comment: windowctrl.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyName.Name, "Notepad", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));

Comment: Thank you, have you got a good link that I can look at so that I can learn more about this?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SmartMatchOptions = SmartMatchOptions.TopLevelWindow;
```

For more help: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.playbacksettings.smartmatchoptions)